# get parent element by class using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have following html structure for example.

```
<div class="message" data-id="4">
        <div>
            <div class="msg-button">
                <span class="sms"></span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <span class="sms"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

When i click on elements with class `sms` i need to get data-id attribute of element with class `message`.

What i've done using jquery. It doesn't work for me. How can i get parent element by class?
Thanks in advance!

```
$('.sms').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).parent('.msg-button').siblings('.message').data("id");
    alert(id);
})
```

Comment: [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) - `$(this).closest('.message').data("id");`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/). [.parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) will search only the direct parent node, since you are looking for a matching ancestor element use [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```js
$('.sms').click(function() {
  var id = $(this).closest('.message').data("id");
  alert(id);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="message" data-id="4">
  <div>
    <div class="msg-button">
      <span class="sms"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <span class="sms">sms</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks it works, but i have another issue, what if my spans are not children of parent with class message, what should i use instead of method closest. For more information i'll provide this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g2Rxc/93/

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [`parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) instead of [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)

```
$('.sms').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).parents('.message').data("id");
    alert(id);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to find the ancestor in hierarchy with specified selector

```
$('.sms').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).closest('.message').data("id");
    alert(id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

.parents(selector)
 ParentS will search up in the DOM